# Access $http data from outside function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Sorry if the title hasn't made much sense, I don't really know a better way of explaining.

I have the following...

```js
app.controller('viewProductController', ['$scope', 'dataFactory', '$routeParams', function($scope, dataFactory, $routeParams) {

        dataFactory.getProduct($routeParams.viewProduct)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.product = data[0];
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            });
  }]);
```

```js
factory('dataFactory', ['$http', function($http) {

        var urlBase = 'get.php?get=';
        var dataFactory = {};

        dataFactory.getProducts = function () {
            return $http.get(urlBase + 'products');
        };
  }]);
```

It works perfectly when I go to the DOM and use `{{product.product_name}}` (example), but what I want also is to be able to use `$scope.product.product_name` inside the controller, however it comes up undefined.

I think this is because `$scope.product` is set inside of a function, therefore I cannot get this outside of the function.

If I use `console.log($scope.product);` inside the same function it is set, I see the array inside the console, but if I use it outside of the function where `$scope.product` is set, I cannot access and it says undefined.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a scope issue.  `$scope` is available throughout the controller, it is not limited to the scope of your calling function.

You're not able to access `$scope.product` because the variable is being set asynchronously.  This means `$scope.product` isn't available until `dataFactory.getProduct` is called and returns a successful request.  If you want `$scope.product` to be used in other parts of your controller, you must wait for it to be assigned first.

You can do this with a `$watch`.  Let's say you have a function called `myFunction()` that needs to use `$scope.product` and you want `myFunction()` to be called on page load.

Something like

```
$scope.myFunction = function(){
    console.log($scope.product);
}
// You'll get undefined here since $scope.product needs to be set first
$scope.myFunction();
```

The above won't print out the correct value in console.  But the below will:

```
$scope.$watch('product', function(newValue){
    if(typeof newValue != 'undefined'){
        $scope.myFunction();
    }
});
```

You're essentially saying anytime `$scope.product` changes value, call `$scope.myFunction()`

Answer (score 1):

> I think this is because $scope.product is set inside of a function,
>   therefore I cannot get this outside of the function.

No, it's not a function scope issue, it's a timing issue.

The `$http.get` method is asynchronous, which means that the `success` callback that you specify will be called when the response arrives.

You can't access the data outside the callback function, because it doesn't exist yet. Anything that you want to use the data for has to be executed from within the callback function, otherwise it will run before the data is available.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not an inside/outside problem... your problem is a before/after problem!

When your controller is executed, it launches a request for data, but it takes some time to complete. The rest of the controller code is executed immediately, but $scope.product is not yet assigned.

You can set a $watch on the product variable and do whatever you need to do when it's value changes

```
$scope.$watch('product', function(newValue,oldValue){

    // do whatever

});
```